# Can we trigger $digest without using $apply in Angular js?

Tags: angularjs, scope, apply, angularjs-digest

As i was going through the life cycle of scope, I came across `$digest` should be called by `$apply`. But I want to know if possible can we enable `$digest` without `$apply`. If yes what is disadvantage

Comment: refer http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you calls the `$scope.$apply()` function, it call the `$rootScope.$digest()`. So as a result of that, digest cycle starts from the rootScope and call all the child scopes.

you can call the digest using `$scope.$digest()` but this will start the cycle for child scope only. sometimes binding will not properly occur because digest cycle is not starting from the root scope.

you can check [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/understanding-two-way-binding-sachila-ranawaka) article to get an idea about how the digest cycle works

Comment: Thanks i was knowing its process but i was not aware of $scope.apply() function which calls the $rootScope.$digest().

Answer (score 0):

The `$scope.$digest()` function iterates through all the watches in the `$scope` object, and its child `$scope` objects (if it has any). When `$digest()` iterates over the watches, it calls the value function for each watch.

The `$scope.$apply()` function takes a function as parameter which is executed, and after that `$scope.$digest()` is called internally.